# Process latest file from GetS/List SFTP processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am getting multiple files from List SFTP processor. However the requirement is to only process the latest file based on last modification time of file. I tried merging files via merge content processor , but the last modification time goes away. Current version of Nifi is 1.6, so record set writer can't be used. How can the solution for it be implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `AttributesTo*Processor` and create a new flow file from `filename` and `file.lastModifiedTime` attributes. Then you can merge content to get a single flow file with both filename and modifiedtime. You should be able to able to get the file from here.

Answer (score 0):

In listsftp you can see the property called maxfileAge , use that to find the latest file